# OmniSharp Error E216

Tags: vim, omnicomplete, spf13vim

I have installed omnisharp after spf13. I copied/paste script [example vimrc](https://github.com/nosami/Omnisharp) to my `.vimrc.local`.

After launching vim I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing C:\Users\...\_vimrc:

line   59:

E216: No such group or event: TextChanged,InsertLeave *.cs SyntasticCheck
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextChanged` event is a fairly recent addition. You need Vim 7.4 for it, or a Vim 7.3.882 (approximately) or later.

Comment: Thank you. I installed 7.4 and no error displaied. Other issue: Omnisharp still seems not installed because Omni Command are not known. If you have an idea else I will post a new question.

Comment: Please post separate questions to avoid lengthy discussions.

Comment: Ok done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429994/omnisharp-command-not-recognized